# Регулярное выражение, ложное срабатывание?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Что-то не так с моим регулярным выражением или почему оно срабатывает на данном выражении?

Задача стоит, удалить строки в HTML документе, в которых все ячейки пустые. Фрагмент HTML документа ниже:

```
<tr>
<td collspan="5"> <b>Какой-то текст</b>
</td>
</tr>
```

Регулярное выражение, которым хотел удалить фрагменты:

```
<tr.*?>(<td.*?>|</td>|\s)*</tr>
```

Однако пример попадает под данное выражение.
Такое ощущение, что \s поедает весь текст внутри тега tr, но не могу понять почему.

Comment: `<tr[^>]*>(\s*<td[^>]*>\s*<\/td>)*\s*<\/tr>`

Comment: @splash58, Спасибо, вроде работает.Но не понятно, в чем принципиальная разница моего выражения и этого?

Разве [^>]* не аналог .*?> в моем случае?

Любые символы 0 и более раз кроме > и любые символы как можно меньше до символа >

Comment: зависит от жадности regex'а. Я про сишную библиотеку не знаю, может он сразу до пооледней `>` выгоебает

Comment: @splash58, так быть должно, если бы я написал ".*", но я для этого поставил символ "?", чтобы получилось ".*?" - как можно меньше. Вот и удивляюсь, что не так-то? -_-

Comment: @Pincher1519, `чтобы получилось ".*?" - как можно меньше.` это не означает, что будет захвачен минимальный участок, если больший участок текста подходит под регулярку, а этот меньший - нет. Посмотрите в дебаге `Regex Debugger` как себя ведет https://regex101.com/r/lG7eT9/1 регулярка.

Comment: Что-то никому не хочется писать ответ :) А ведь с HtmlAgilityPack проще.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я пробовал его использовать. Однако он выполняет операции в 10-ки раз медленнее.

Comment: Да, но точность и простота использования совсем другие. А если в ячейке будет вложенная таблица?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ничего страшного, ячейка заполненная, ее пропускаем, и смотрим дальше.

Answer (score 1):

В регулярных выражениях .NET точка работает примерно также, как и в других библиотеках регулярных выражений, отличных от POSIX: точка находит любой символ, отличный от знака перевода строки (`"\n"`). Квантификатор `*?` находит не кратчайшую подстроку, он находит столько символов, сколько понадобится для нахождения совпадения. Так как строка (как и регулярка) анализируется слева направо (по умолчанию), `<td.*?>` найдёт `<td`, потом 0 и более символов, отличных от символа перевода строки, до первого вхождения `>`, **за которым следует `</tr>`**. Если бы не было `</tr>`, `<td.*?>` нашло бы `<td collspan="5">`, как ожидалось.

***Решение***: чтобы не выходить за рамки одного тега, используйте исключающий символьный класс `[^<>]*`, `[^<]*?` или `[^>]*`. Если внутри тега могут быть несериализованные `<` или `>`, например `<tr><td name="<67"></td></tr>`, понадобится [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) (англ.) ("жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор) `(?:(?!</?[a-zA-Z]).)*`, который не найдет такие символы, с которых начинается тег (`<a` или `</a`).

#### Лучше всего воспользоваться HTML-парсером - "тише едешь — дальше будешь".

В большинстве случаев подойдёт:

```
<tr[^<]*?>(<td[^<]*?>|</td>|\s)*</tr>
```

[См. демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Ctr%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3F%3E%28%3Ctd%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3F%3E%7C%3C%2Ftd%3E%7C%5Cs%29*%3C%2Ftr%3E&i=%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%20collspan%3D%225%22%3E%20%3Cb%3E%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%3C%2Fb%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E)